# What neural network can I use to predict data from stock exchange data set?

Tags: forecasting, deep-learning, finance

I am doing a school project based on a scientific paper that predict data from a stock exchange data set

First the program use a genetic programing algorithm to get new data, then improves the data using Artificial fish swarm algorithm, then uses a neural network where the first data is the input variables and the latest processed data are the variables to predict

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to commit "voodoo".  If you put money on such a thing, you can quickly lose a lot of money.  If you want to predict, your "basis" should have good alignment with the "physics".  GP can be finicky and the stock market is rough to start with.  If your tool doesn't work well on "easier problems" then it can quickly fail in stocks.  Be exceptionally careful here.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on time-series models, and forget about NN

Comment: The profesor give me the scientific paper and I must do a replique of the work, I must program all the algorithms

Comment: If you are replicating work from a paper, you should read the paper to find out which Neural Network to use, not ask people on the Internet who haven't read your paper.

Comment: I have no idea of how to predict the market. Aside from looking at the entrails of animals, or reading into the night constellations, if I was in your predicament, I would look into recurrent neural nets (RNN) :-)  Here is [one of the many examples](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2012/BernalFokPidaparthi-FinancialMarketTimeSeriesPredictionwithRecurrentNeural.pdf). BTW +1 for the AFS algorithm - really cool!

Comment: the paper only say they use a artificial neural netowrk, they does not say which one

Comment: You can use RNN's to predict time series, or MLPs to model stationary series (since you are just looking at the joint over a fixed window), but there is really no reason to unless you have already used an ARMA model